# My .bashrc dissapeared with all his alias and functions

Tags: linux, bash, reboot, burp

I was working on my VM and occasionally when I have been working for a long time and it is tab overloaded it collapses. Today it collapsed again and when I rebooted my Mozillas icon was not there. No big deal, I opened the terminal I typed one function that I defined time ago and that I usually use and it says that it is not defined. I wanted to check my .bashrc file and to my astonishment it wasn't there. Then I copied my function to /etc/bash.bashrc and i also created /root/.bashrc and added PATH=$PATH:~/bin. After that I wanted to use Burpsuite, which I had it as a command line like as alias or function inside my .bashrc to execute it directly from terminal. As my .bashrc was removed I had to defined the function/alias again but to my astonishment there is no burp.jar or burp directory (and still cant find it).

and now I'm afraid I'm going to find that I'm missing more things.

Does anyone have any idea what could have happened? And any solution to recover?

Thank you so much

I tried to find bashrc with `find / -name .bashrc` and `find / -name *burp*`. `echo "$SHELL"` is `/bin/bash`

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for other sites such as https://superuser.com.

Comment: If files disappear, it means that you (or some other rogue user) has erased them, or that the file system is corrupt, in which case you have a more serious problem. For the time being, just restore the file from your backup.

Comment: Once your .bashrc is gone, you should NEVER execute commands until you have compared the online image to a backup image to identify the discrepencies.  That comparison should be done from a live disk or a USB with the live.  Your original image is completely suspect and any "safe" command may not be do what you expect it to do, but something much more devastating.  Once you've identified the "DELTA", only then can you make a reasonable determination as to whether the corruption is from deliberate external tampering (what should be your first stance) or internal incorrect/accidental coding.